# Как распознать адблок?

Tags: реклама

Как понять что у пользователя стоит адблок и что-то ему вывести?

Comment: А вариант не показывать раздражающую рекламу вы не рассматривали? Я лично, если сайт плохо себя ведёт с включенным адблоком, сразу ухожу с него.

Comment: Хабрахабр как-то определяет. Попробуйте проанализировать их код.

Comment: VladD,логично.Но в моем случае портить сайт не буду.Да и реклама не особо жёсткая

Comment: поэтому я еще и js отключаю. Только вайтлист.

Comment: @VladD все рассчитывают нафигарить сайтиков простых, расположить миллион рекламных блоков и стать миллионером лежа на печи)) И вместо адекватных спонсоров занимаются отталкиванием половины своих посетителей. Потом эти горе блокировщики и сидят на последних страницах поисковика с низким рейтом)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский,просто вам говорить. Адблок порой и адекватных блочит. А есть сайты ,которые вообще не могут конвертироваться тупо ссылками или контекстом. Банеры то можно,но их блочат часто - ага)

Comment: @Maksym "реклама" и "адекватный" - вещи несовместимые)) Если на сайте есть реклама, а тем более еще вдобавок отслеживатель адблока, то грош цена таким сайтам, не стоят внимания. Серьезные и правильные ресурсы не содержат рекламу и баннеры. Они существуют на финансы, которые берут из других источников.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский для меня адекватная это контеест, банеры и просто ссылки.Всё остальное это уже хуже.Но проблема в том что у мелких сайтов не получится получать  прибыль с других источников.Даже тот же хабр с банером и чекером на адблок хоть  типа сайт серьёзный

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/sitexw/FuckAdBlock
Там же можно найти ссылку на демо.

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал в лоб: через небольшой таймаут проверяю размеры контейнера `<div>` внутрь которого должны загрузиться рекламные блоки. Если реклама загрузилась к тому моменту, размеры блока меняются. Нет - либо AdBlock, либо тормоза.

Наверняка есть лучшие решения. Полёз смотреть исходники Хабра и репо на гитхабе..